# <figure> tag behaviour in iBooks, single tap to enlarge?

Tags: html, figure, ibooks, epub3

I am using  to insert an image and caption to the ePub 3 file, which incidentally I need to include a pop-up note on the caption.

Here is the code:

```
<figure>
  <div class="figures">
    <!-- ibooks doesnt read width in img class, has to warp in div -->
    <img class="frame" src="image/01_fmt.jpeg" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <figcaption>
    <p class="imagegroup"><a epub:type="noteref" href="#n1" class="superscript">1</a></p>
    <aside epub:type="footnote" id="n1">
      <p>pop up notes, <i>in italic text here</i>.</p>
    </aside> 
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

It works well, however, I need to double tap the image to enlarge, is it possible—maybe extra markup available—to change it to single tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no additional markup available for this in Epub3 (that I know of). The simplest (IE non JS) solution I can think of is just having an href in the anchor tag that goes either to the image file directly, or to an xhtml page with that image on it (this depends on which reader app your end user is on, in iBooks for example you can link directly to the image, but not in Kindle...).

Hope this helps, happy to post the JS solution if that's something you are interested in!